# Seaborn color palette: how to choose which part to center on (e.g. which end of the plot is red and which end is blue)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I want a catplot of a Pandas dataframe that contains a numerical value for all hours of a year. It has 3 columns: Hour, Weekday, and Value. I plot it like this:

```
cat_weekdayhour = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
cat_weekdayhour = sns.set_context("paper")
cat_weekdayhour = sns.set(style="darkgrid", font_scale=.6)

weekdayhour.shape
cat_weekdayhour = sns.catplot(x="Weekday", y="Value", hue="Hour", kind="swarm", palette="coolwarm", data=dataframe)
```

This gives me the following catplot, but I don't like how the early hours of a day (like 0-4 AM) are very blue and then the last hours (8-11 PM) are red. **Instead**, I want to center the ***RED color to the DAY hours*** and then make ***all the night hours blue***. Can this be done? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: That would mean you want to have non-unique colors, i.e. light blue would apply to 5 am as well as 10 pm? (I think the desired outcome needs a little more explanation.)

Comment: Yes that's a good point that they wouldn't be unique, but I think that would be perfect for this purpose. Do you know how this could be done? 

Would be nice to try with unique colors as well but so that night hours were dark and day hours bright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own pallete by combining "coolwarm" with its reveresed pallette. I have an older version of `seaborn` so I'll use swarmplot to illustrate

## Sample Data

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 1000
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weekday': ['Friday']*n,
                   'Hour': np.random.randint(0,24,n),
                   'Value': np.random.randint(40,150,n)})
```

#### coolwarm palette

```
sns.swarmplot(x="Weekday", y="Value", hue="Hour", palette="coolwarm", data=df)
```

[image]

#### Custom palette

```
# 24 hours so split evenly between the two
mypal = sns.color_palette("coolwarm", 12) + sns.color_palette("coolwarm_r", 12)
sns.swarmplot(x="Weekday", y="Value", hue="Hour", palette=mypal, data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for, the day hours are now red and night hours are blue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just be careful, I'm not 100% sure this will order properly if the hours are strings, may be best to convert to integer hours by stripping before `':'`

Answer (score 3):

One idea can be to create a new colormap, let's call it `"cycliccoolwarm"` which contains the original colormap and a reversed version of it. Then using this new colormap is as easy as any other existing colormap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Day" : np.repeat(np.array(list("1234567")),24*40 ),
                   "Hour" : np.tile(np.arange(0,24), 7*40).astype(int),
                   "Value" : np.random.rand(7*24*40)*180})
df['Hour'] = df['Hour'].apply('{:02d}:00'.format)

cmap_orig = plt.get_cmap("coolwarm")
colors = cmap_orig(np.concatenate((np.linspace(0,1,128), np.linspace(1,0,128))))
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
plt.cm.register_cmap("cycliccoolwarm", cmap=cmap)

g = sns.catplot(x="Day", y="Value", hue="Hour", kind="swarm", palette="cycliccoolwarm", data=df)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Hour` column in your dataframe as a source for the coloring. Instead, you could introduce a new column that containes the values from Hour relative to 12:00:

```
dataframe['Color'] = -abs(dataframe['Hour'] - 12)
```

So 12:00 will become 0, 24:00 will become -12. 6:00 and 18:00 will become -6.
This way the middle of the day will be represented by the highest value (red → 0) while midnight will be represented by the lowest value (blue → -12).

Comment: That would mean 17h becomes the dark reddests, and 18h becomes the dark bluest?

Comment: No, as I wrote 18 h will end up in the middle of the new range [0, 12]. So it will be gray.

Comment: Other than what I wrote in my previous comment, the range is in fact [-12, 0] when you want midnight as the lowest point.

Comment: I see. This makes sense and would actually work if seaborn understood it. Which unfortunately is not the case; as despite its name  `hue` is actually just another dimesion of the data. So you would get the correct plot out, but the legend would still look similar, and only comprise the shifted 12 hours.

Comment: This sounds good and I'm working on it (getting the "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'" which I'm guessing is because the values in my Hour column are objects instead of datetime), but I saw now @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's comment. Are there any other ways to get this if this suggestion doesn't work?

Comment: Probably, I'm still in the course of typing in some data to produce a runnable example. (That could of course have been prevented by supplying one in the question, [mcve])

Comment: Sorry for that, I wasn't certain if I could share this dataset. Thank you for your help.